# Attempting to call unbound fn: #'datoteka.core/to-file

Tags: clojure

I am very new to clojure and I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'datoteka.core/to-file
at clojure.lang.Var$Unbound.throwArity(Var.java:45)
at clojure.lang.AFn.invoke(AFn.java:32)
at package.auth_monitor$start_monitor_thread.invokeStatic(auth_monitor.clj:43)
at package.auth_monitor$start_monitor_thread.invoke(auth_monitor.clj:38)
at package.auth_monitor$start_monitor.invokeStatic(auth_monitor.clj:62)
at package.auth_monitor$start_monitor.invoke(auth_monitor.clj:49)
at package.auth_monitor$fn__11768.invokeStatic(auth_monitor.clj:71)
at package.auth_monitor$fn__11768.invoke(auth_monitor.clj:70)
```

the code is:

```
42. (let [^TailerListener listener (make-listener)
43.    ^File file (fs/to-file path)
44.    ^Tailer tailer (Tailer. file listener 1000 true)]
45. (doto (Thread. tailer)
46.  (.setDaemon false)
47.  (.start)))
```

Comment: Indeed, there is no function `to-file` in `datoteka.core`. Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I inherited the project, but I guess the previous dev was trying to create a thread to listen to changes to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are using the [Datoteka](https://github.com/funcool/datoteka) library. Try using the `file` function to get a `File` object based on the path (`to-file` seems to be a wrong name):

```
(let [^TailerListener listener (make-listener)
      ^File file (fs/file path)
      ^Tailer tailer (Tailer. file listener 1000 true)]
  (doto (Thread. tailer)
    (.setDaemon false)
    (.start)))
```